# Call view controller function from delegate class

Tags: swift, delegates

I'm relatively new to swift and I'm having issues trying to call a function in a view controller from a delegate I have defined. How can I call the function in my view controller from this delegate? This is a mixed project consisting of mostly Objective-C code with only one Swift controller. The function is inside of the Swift controller. Below is the delegate class:

```
class DelegateToHandle302:NSObject, URLSessionTaskDelegate {
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, willPerformHTTPRedirection response: HTTPURLResponse, newRequest request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping (URLRequest?) -> Void) {

    //convert to https
    let http = request.url!
    var comps = URLComponents(url: http, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)!
    comps.scheme = "https"
    let httpsUrl = comps.url!

    ViewControllerFunction(url: httpsUrl)

}
```

I get an error Use of unresolved identifier 'ViewControllerFunction'. I've tried creating an instance of the view controller but don't think that's the correct way to do it as this view controller also has an audio player (it also didn't work).

Here is where I call the delegate from a function inside the view controller:

```
    let urlString = "https://urlthatredirects.com"
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let url = URL(string: urlString)

    //set delegate value equal to SessionDelegate to handle 302 redirect
    let delegate = DelegateToHandle302()

    //establish url session
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: delegate, delegateQueue: nil)

    //set task with url
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url!)

    //init call
    dataTask.resume()
```

I'm following part of an example on how to get the final URL from a redirection (https://gist.github.com/mgersty/b565ba4c9e9422637f15f52a5317f07e). My view controllers "header" is:

```
@objc class AudioPlayerController: UIViewController{........}
```

I hope I've provided enough info to allow anyone to assist me in figuring out what I'm doing wrong. The only thing I need to do is call that function and pass the redirection URL to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit confused about what you're trying to do, and why you're trying to call a delegate method back into the VC rather than using the completion handler; but I think you've got your delegate pattern back-to-front.  I'm assuming the idea is:

1. the view controller instiagtes the URL session
2. the url sessions passes of the result of the URLSession to the DelegateToHandle302 to process
3. DelegateToHandle302 then tries to run a method back in the view controller that launched it.

If this is the case you actually need the VC to be the delegate of the DelegateToHandle302 class, not the other way around.

So within your view controller

```
let handlerFor302 = DelegateToHandle302()
handlerFor302.delegate = self. 

let session = URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: handlerFor302, delegateQueue: nil
   //etc... as before
```

Create a protocol for the delegate to adopt, which defines the desired function

```
protocol URLProcessor {
   func  ViewControllerFunction(url: URL)
}
```

The adopt the protocol in your view controller and implement the method

```
extension MyViewController: URLProcessor {
   func  ViewControllerFunction(url: URL) { .... do whatever ...}
```

and then use the delegate with the protocol method in your DelegateToHandle302

```
class DelegateToHandle302:NSObject, URLSessionTaskDelegate {
   weak var delegate: URLProcessor? 

   func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, willPerformHTTPRedirection response: HTTPURLResponse, newRequest request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping (URLRequest?) -> Void) {

    //Process the output

    delegate?.ViewControllerFunction(url: httpsUrl)
}
```

Comment: This worked and thank you for your detailed explanation. In order to make that weak var delegate: URLProcessor? work, I had to also make the protocol inherit from class (protocol URLProcessor: class {...}. Would you suggest that I not use a back-to-front pattern for delegation?

Comment: Could there be any reason why my audio no longer plays? Inside of the ViewControllerFunction, I have the following: let playerItem:AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: httpsUrl);
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem);
        player?.play();

Comment: I guess I also spoke too soon, it seems that the `weak var delegate: URLProcessor?` is always nil so this isn't working. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Not sure why the URLProcessorprotocol needs to inherit the other protocol - it should be the VC that conforms to both protocols.

Comment: In the VC you specifically set the delegate in `handlerFor302.delegate = self` so I can't see any way it can be nil unless at some point you reinitialise the 'handlerFor302` and so overwrite the instance with the delegate property set.  Updating the question with the relevant code from the viewController might help.

Comment: It seems I need to brush up on delegates. I had to add `handlerFor302.delegate = self` in my ViewDidLoad. It's now working!